# Accidental delete iOS framework

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

So i have been having the hardest time getting my iphone application approved. And i sorta when on a little rampage through some of my code.

In my shear stupidity I thought that maybe I did not need the `SenTestingKit.framework`. So i attempted to remove it from my program, and when asked if i would like to delete or remove references i accidently clicked delete.

However upon reviewing some crash logs PRE-Deletion of SenTestingKit.framework I found the following...

[image]

Again this error was before I deleted the framework. The crash code to this is `0xe7ffdefe`

Could someone please tell me where i might get the sentestingkit.framework from? And also if you have anyidea why it is causing the crash that would be so amazing to hear.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I have not tried that yet, i was hoping to be able to just download it somewheres, but i guess thats an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To restore that framework, just re-install Xcode. Or maybe your trash still has it.

About the iOS devices that complain about not finding the SenTestkingKit: I'd assume so, as it's a Xcode-only framework used for test cases. You aren't supposed to link it when distributing the app. Why would the user want to run test cases?

Comment: Right, well I just dont have any idea where I used it or what it is used for. But your right, I bet that it could be causing the crash where i used it. Any idea what its used for?

Comment: Yeah, it's used for [test cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_case). But it's only available on the simulator, and that's why it crashes on a device.

Comment: Any idea how i might track down where I've used it?

Comment: Remove the framework from the references and find out where it starts throwing errors.

Comment: Well thats just the thing, Ive got it pulled out, i don't even have it on my computer...

Comment: But is it still linked in your project?  If so...of course it will complain about not being found :-S